# Rails devise two separate registration forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am building a Doctor booking platform where there's a patient and a doctor.

I currently have standard devise setup with one user model and one signup form, I want to have to separate forms one for patient where I will pass params role of patient and a doctor form with params of doctor role so I can assign roles from the controller or the model.

The forms will be quite the same only for doctor I will require some extra fields.

Also my doctor as it belongs to a user will have the ability to book an appointment with other doctors, is it a good practice to use boolean to define whether it's a doctor or not or use roles with enum.

I need help please

Comment: SO is not a great place for getting people to design your software with you. Unless you can present a specific coding question it is not likely to meet the basic requirements for a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `hidden_field_tag`, did you have tried anything or want to clear concept? You can do this using `hidden_field_tag` like if you create those form using bootstrap tab like this

```js
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Doctor</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
<h2>Just example form</h2>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    <h2>Doctor?</h2>
    <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <h2>Patient?</h2>
        <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

in the form, you can just use a hidden field like when form for **doctor**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :role, value: "doctor" %>
```

and when form for **Patient**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :role, value: "patient" %>
```

and permit their `role` in the `application_controller`

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :role])
end
```

I thing it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes it worked now am trying to make another signup page for the doctor.